# how to increase only top-height of crop image?

Tags: html, css

now i want to increase only top height of image . is it possibl ? also can we use `clip:rect()` without using posiion absolute ?

```
a.rollover img {
    position : absolute; 
    clip:rect(16px,60px,200px,0px);
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
}

a.rollover:hover > img {
    position : absolute; 
    clip:rect(6px,60px,200px,0px);
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
}

<a class="rollover"><img src="dest.jpg" /></a>
```

Comment: [What doesn't work?](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/8uJet/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to use `clip: rect()` without using `position: absolute`. You should be seeing and increase of the image height on your `:hover` effect by `10px` (from `16px` clip to `6px` clip).

However, your `200px` for bottom seems to show a misunderstanding of clip. I've found [this article](http://www.ibloomstudios.com/articles/misunderstood_css_clip/) to be very helpful in my understanding `clip`. Basically you are setting the top-left corner by the first and last of the four numbers, and the bottom-right corner ***as referenced from the top-left corner of the full element*** (this is different than `margin`, `padding`, etc.).

```
           ^              ^
           | Top          |
           v              |
<--Left--->*              |Bottom
                          |
                          |
                          v
<--------Right----------->*
```